# Finding Shared Network Folder and Active Directory Information

Tags: powershell, active-directory, attributes, file-sharing

I have a script that I'm using to try to find Shared network folder and subfolder information such as the folder owner, AD groups associated to the Network shared folder or subfolder, AD group notes, AD group description, AD group manager, and AD group manager email.

I'm currently having a hard time trying to figure out why none of this data is showing when I export this to a .csv file. I would appreciate any help or guidance.

```
# Find the owner of the Network Folders and the AD Groups they got access to and the details of those AD Groups (name, description, managedby and ema $FolderPath = $DomainName =
Start-Transcript $PSScriptRoot\Transcript.txt

$FolderPath = "\\server\foldername"
$DomainName = "Domain"       # as in   Domain\ADGroupName

write-Host "Getting All the permissions of a Folder and its subfolder..."
$ACLS = @()
$Acls += Get-Item $FolderPath | get-acl
$ACLs += Get-ChildItem $FolderPath -Recurse -Directory

$results = @()

foreach($acl in $acls)
{
    $Domain = $DomainName.Split(".")[0]
    write-Host "  Getting Access ADGroup details"
    $AllDomainAccess = $acl.Access | Where-Object { $_.identityReference -like "$Domain\*" }

    foreach($DomainAccess in $AllDomainAccess)
    {
        $ADGroup = $null
        $ADGroup = get-ADGroup $($DomainAccess.IdentityReference).value.split("\")[-1] -Properties * -server $DomainName  -ea SilentlyContinue

        if($null -ne $ADGroup)
        {
            $data = '' | Select-Object FolderPath, FolderOwner, AccessGroup, AccessGroup_Description, AccessGroup_ManagedBy, AccessGroup_ManagerEmail
            $data.FolderPath = $acl.Path.split(":")[-1]
            $data.FolderOwner = $acl.Owner
            $data.AccessGroup = $ADGroup.Name
            $data.AccessGroup_Description = $ADGroup.Description
            $data.AccessGroup_ManagedBy = $ADGroup.ManagedBy
            $data.AccessGroup_ManagerEmail = $(get-aduser $($ADGroup.ManagedBy) -Properties mail).mail

            $results += $data
        }

}
}

$results | export-csv "$PSScriptRoot\NetworkFolderPermissions.csv" -NoTypeInformation
write-Host "Saved the results in $PSScriptRoot\NetworkFolderPermissions.csv" -ForegroundColor Green

Stop-Transcript
```

Comment: Are the spaces between the object `$data.`  and the Property name a typo or a copy-paste error?

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon, copy-paste error. Even when I fix those typos, it doesn't seem to provide any data on the .csv file

Comment: for starters, `Get-ChildItem $FolderPath -Recurse -Directory` seem to be missing a pipe to `Get-Acl`

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon, now receiving these errors when I pipe Get-Acl after -Directory

https://gyazo.com/ab00b3098f0f8daef3f752e413271482

Comment: The line `$data.AccessGroup_ManagerEmail` has a `-` instead of an `=`

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon, that fixes the first error that I was seeing, but am still getting the second one... I've updated my code to the latest fixes

Comment: The second error just means that the ADGroup doesn't have any value for it's `ManagedBy` attribute, hence `Get-ADUser` throws that error